# Installing ODBC drivers for sql serve on mac os 10.13 running R

Tags: sql, r, unixodbc

I am getting the following error when attempting to run the following command in R

**Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:983: 00000: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found**

After doing some digging, I've seen where I need to install ODBC driver unixODBC. I haven't the slightest clue how to.

I've attempted to solve using brew install process in the command terminal on my macbook pro, but still no luck. Can anyone help please

[My script with commands and errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWDCJ.png)

[After running devtools with gethub for RSQLServer package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCQPM.png)

Comment: This is the link to the method that worked for me when I did this. I find using `brew install` solves some problems I was having with manual installs: https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2017/05/15/odbc-driver-13-1-for-macos-released/

Comment: Update: 
installed brew through the command terminal; 
installed unixodbc with brew; 
installed ODBC drivers; 
ran this step (wget “https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/master/samples/tutorials/c/linux/sample_c_linux.c“ ) and get the message scheme is missing. 
Ran in R: con <- dbConnect(odbc(), Driver = "SQL Server",Server = "S02ASQLP335", Database = "NAP", Trusted_Connection = "True")...
I get the same error: Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:983: 00000: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found

Comment: Are you using `DBI` package?

Comment: Yes, I attached a screen shot of my script and the errors in the main body above

Comment: So, two things `install.packages('RSQLServer')  and also `odbc` and `DBI` are wrapped in some ways, I expressly request from each using `::`  like this:  `conn<-::dbConnect(RSQLServer::SQLServer(),
                       server ='someserver'....)` see if after installing `RSQLServer` and using the above language it works for you.

Comment: RSQLServer and SQLServer packages are not available.

Comment: really...I just installed them recently...hmm

Comment: Try this to get it from the source: https://www.r-project.org/nosvn/pandoc/RSQLServer.html

Comment: Attempted that. See Script above.

Comment: the screen shot show multiple syntax to attempt the same sql server connects

Answer (score 0):

As error indicates, there is no *SQL Server* driver on your system using your screenshot. However, your system shows an *ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server* name, a different version as is *ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server* and *ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server*. Therefore rename appropriately:

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                      Driver = "ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server",
                      Server = "***",
                      Database = "***",
                      Trusted_Connection = "Yes")
```